# Create file that keeps time and revision number of my project when I compile

Tags: linux, jsp, svn, ant, build

Currently the file is only keeping the latest revision. I want to use a different file where the history is kept. Each time ANT is used, I want it to append the time and revision number on that file. On the home screen I will just have a link to that file.

This is how its written now:

```
<target name="compile-java" depends="prepare,compile"> 
        <exec dir="${project.dir}" executable="tools/version.sh" output="${src.web.dir}/date_compile.jsp">
            <arg line="" />
        </exec> 
        <propertyfile file="${src.web.dir}/date_compile.jsp">
        </propertyfile>
   </target>
```

I want to append new revision while keeping old revision data too.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a Version Control System. If not, please explain further.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: when i build my project, the build.xml include this <target name="compile-java" depends="prepare,compile"> 
 <target name="compile-java" depends="prepare,compile"> 
  <exec dir="${project.dir}" executable="tools/version.sh" output="${src.web.dir}/ ">
      <arg line="" />
  </exec> 
  <propertyfile file="${src.web.dir}/date_compile.jsp">
  </propertyfile>
   </target>
basically throw my build version into the jsp file. the problem with every new build it overwrite the whole file so i cant keep a history of my builds version. I want to append new revision while keeping old revision data too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a matter of using the [BuildNumber](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/buildnumber.html) or [PropertyFile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html) task to create the build version number file and then read the file to get that number, create also a timestamp of the build and then append them both to another file.

[Here is a basic idea of how to do it](http://stephensoftware.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/auto-increment-version-numbers-in-ant/). Starting from that you should be able to write something of the likes of this:

```
<project default="increment">
    <target name="increment">
        <tstamp>
            <format property="build.time" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />
        </tstamp>
        <propertyfile file="build.properties">
            <entry key="build.number" type="int" operation="+" default="0" />
        </propertyfile>
        <property file="build.properties" />
        <echo message="Build ${build.number} on ${build.time}&#13;&#10;" append="true" file="build.history" />
    </target>
</project>
```

This creates two files: `build.properties` with your build number (always the last number as it is overwritten on each build) and `build.history` that contains a list of build numbers and a timestamp of each build.

**EDIT :** Based on the comments, if the `version.sh` outputs the revision and date to `date_compile.jsp` and overrides it on each build then - to keep history - you just need to load `date_compile.jsp` in your build and append its content to another file, something like this:

```
<target name="compile-java" depends="prepare,compile">
    <exec dir="${project.dir}" executable="tools/version.sh" output="${src.web.dir}/date_compile.jsp">
        <arg line="" />
    </exec>
    <loadfile property="revision" srcfile="${src.web.dir}/date_compile.jsp" />
    <echo message="${revision}&lt;br&gt;&#13;&#10;" append="true" file="${src.web.dir}/compile_history.jsp" />
</target>
```

Comment: This is really helpful Thank you. but i'm sorry i wasnt very clear, i need to create a file that contains the build number and the revision as well. in the 
version.sh it includes
 #!/bin/bash

# echo `svn info|grep branch|awk -F\/ '{ print $NF }'`"/"`svnversion`
echo `git branch | sed --quiet 's/* \(.*\)/\1/p'`"/"`git log --pretty=format:'%h/%cd' --date=short -n 1`
so im kinda confused, do i need to change in that file or the build.xml
thanks

Comment: @Saad Yehia El Ashmawi: That depends on what will be easier for you. You can change the file to make it keep the history or you can load the file in the ANT build with something like `<loadfile property="revision" srcfile="youtRevision.file" />` and then add that to the echo: `<echo message="Build ${build.number} on ${build.time} revision ${revision}&#13;&#10;" append="true" file="build.history" />`.

Comment: thank you, i will give this one a try. but if i want to keep the history in the version.sh how that could be done?

Comment: this is how we save the revision and the build now 
<target name="compile-java" depends="prepare,compile"> 
  <exec dir="${project.dir}" executable="tools/version.sh" output="${src.web.dir}/date_compile.jsp">
      <arg line="" />
  </exec> 
  <propertyfile file="${src.web.dir}/date_compile.jsp">
  </propertyfile>
   </target>
all i'm trying to do copy from either version.sh or date_compile.jsp to another file that keep the history
Thanks

Comment: @Saad Yehia El Ashmawi: If you have the content in the `date_compile.jsp` you can load it with `<loadfile>` into your build and write it back to another file with `<echo ... append="true">` as I showed in my comment. [The `<exec>` task itself has an `append` attribute](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) that will allow to keep the history directly. I'm not too familiar with Bash, if you want to modify the `version.sh` file instead, so you are on your own on that one.

Comment: No i won't be able to modify the bash, it's far too complex for me.
I did write it almost same way you did here but i don't get the file content into the compile_history.jsp, im sure there is something missing in my syntax, thanks for your help 
<target name="increment"> 
  <echo message="===============increment======================================" />
  <loadfile property="${src.web.dir}/date_compile.jsp" srcFile="src/web/date_compile.jsp"/>
  <echo message="${src.web.dir}/date_compile.jsp" append="true" file="${src.web.dir}/compile_history.jsp" />
   </target>

Comment: @Saad Yehia El Ashmawi: See my updated answer. Tell me if that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: @Saad Yehia El Ashmawi: you are welcome. Remember you can also mark the answer as accepted if it solved your situation :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you want, but it looks like a combination of `<tstamp/>`, `<echo>`, and `<propertyfile/>`.

You can use `<propertyfile>` to specify the property file where the build number is stored, and for editing it:

```
 <propertyfile file="${build.prop.file}">
    <entry key="build.number"
   value="1"
   default="0"
   operation="+"/>
</propertyfile>
```

Now, you can include that property file in your build:

```
<property file="${build.prop.file}"/>
```

Which will set `${build.number}`.

Next, you're going to get the date and time:

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="build.time.stamp"
        pattern="yyyy-mmm-dd.hh:mm:ss-zzzzz"/>
</tstamp>
```

Now, you'll append this to your log file

```
<echo append="true" file="${build.log}"
    message="Building build # ${build.number} on ${build.time.stamp}"/>
```